# Python Как сделать, чтобы для определенного аудио выполнялось свое условие?

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии песни выполнялось условие принадлежащее ей?

```py
pesni = ["Неизвестная песня.mp3",
                 "Неизвестная песня 2.mp3",
                 "Неизвестная песня 3.mp3"]
audio1 = open(random.choice(pesni), 'rb')
bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio1, title="Откуда же?")
if bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, "Неизвестная песня.mp3"):
    print('123')
elif bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, "Неизвестная песня 2.mp3"):
    print("456")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
track_name = random.choice(pesni)
audio1 = open(track_name, 'rb')
if track_name == "Неизвестная песня.mp3":
    print("Песня 1")
elif track_name == "Неизвестная песня 2.mp3":
    print("Песня 2")
```